# La aplicación se detuvo - Android Studio

Tags: android

Estoy realizando una app con Android Studio y al probarlo en algunos dispositivos físicos me funciona correctamente en unos y en otros me aparece el mensaje "La aplicación se detuvo" antes de ejecutar el primer Activity.

Por ejemplo, me funciona bien en las versiones 5.0, 5.1, 6.0.1, y 7.1 (Probado con dispositivos físicos), pero no se ejecuta en la versión 4.4.2 y 4.1.2

Ya instalé el Android SDK para esa versión pero sigue sin ejecutar. ¿Como podría solucionar esto?

Error arrojado en el Log al instalar e intentar ejecutar el APK en un Android 4.1.2:

```
05-14 16:44:01.911 7758-7758/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-14 16:44:02.161 7758-7758/com.didierzuniga.domix I/ActivityThread: Pub com.didierzuniga.domix.firebaseinitprovider: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
05-14 16:44:02.161 7758-7758/com.didierzuniga.domix D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-14 16:44:02.161 7758-7758/com.didierzuniga.domix W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412212a0)
05-14 16:44:02.171 7758-7758/com.didierzuniga.domix E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4609)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4236)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4178)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:134)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4594)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4236) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4178) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:134) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Agrego el Build Gradle de la app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.didierzuniga.domix"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.zoonref:simple-view-behavior:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

PDT: El minimo SDK que tengo es para la versión 4.0

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle por favor

Comment: Agregado el build gradle de la app

Comment: Veo que agregas varias library de Firebase, que realiza tu aplicacion?

Comment: Una app para domicilios, la cual quiero mostrar los datos en tiempo real mediante FirebaseDatabase y la autenticación de usuarios también con Firebase

Comment: Iguala la versión de firebase con las versiones de services. Si utilizas la 10.0.1 para services utiliza la 10.0.1 para firebase también, a mi me pasó eso con el multidex ya activado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que Java tiene un limite de 65K metodos (funciones declaradas) antes de Lolipop, despues tambien pero es otra historia. Google decidió meter todo en play services y poco a poco esa librería se hizo inmensa. Lo cual al tener firebase tambien pues te pasaste del límite.

Decidieron dar soporte a multi dex. Es decir multiples archivos intermedios que tenian distinto limite de funciones por decirlo de una manera. Por eso activaste el multidex true. Pero pre-lolipop no es facil el soporte y quedo como a medias.

Lo ideal es splitear play services y quitar el multidex. En lugar de usar

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

Usa cualquiera de estas :

```
Google Maps     com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6  
Google Analytics    com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.6
```

Para más 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Hola Arturo, estoy probando, me aparecieron unos warning pero ya los solucioné, pero este es el que no he podido ver como solucionarlo:
Logcat:
Error:(59, 36) error: cannot access zzanb
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanb not found

Y el Jump to source me envía a una declaración que tengo de Firebase:

firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Voy a seguir revisando

Comment: Eso es por que estas usando una versión distinta a la que esa libreria necesita. google comprime sus librerias con progard y eso siempre estan como zzand o xxyyzz. Intenta actualizar todas las librerias a las ultimas versiones pero que entre ellas esten compatibles. O deja que Gradle busque sus dependencias

Comment: Listo Arturo, muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo presente un problema similar y esto sucedía por que tenia que mi clase "Main" como "abstrac" solo la modifique quitando que fuera abstracta y funciono perfectamente.